# How to cast object from an array

Tags: c#, casting

A simple question...

I have an abstract class Cell and two classes BorderCell and BoardCell, which inherit from the Cell class. Then I have a Cells array with the type of Cell[], which contains objects of the type BorderCell and BoardCell.

```
abstract class Cell 
{
}
class BorderCell : Cell 
{
    public void Method1(){};
}
class BoardCell: Cell
{
    public void Method2(){};
}

...

Cell[] Cells = new Cell[x];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    Cells[i] = new BorderCell();
    // or
    Cells[i] = new BoardCell();
}
```

Now I want to cast a cell to BorderCell and run its Method1, like this:

```
(Border)Cells[i].Method1();
```

But this doesn't work, I have to use:

```
BorderCell borderCell = (BorderCell)Cells[i];
borderCell.Method1();
```

Is this the only (and the right way) to do this)?

Comment: I would review your design here -- having to cast back up to derived classes is a bad design smell -- if you're saving them in the same collection as a base type, I would expect them to be truly polymorphic (Liskov Principle).

Comment: Dr Herbie: I am open to suggestions, view this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140281/what-data-structure-to-use-in-my-example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you just need brackets to make it clear what you want the cast to apply to:

```
((Border)Cells[i]).Method1();
```

Basically the "." binds tighter than the cast, so your original code:

```
(Border)Cells[i].Method1();
```

is equivalent to:

```
(Border)  (Cells[i].Method1());
```

Comment: Jon is quick on the trigger today (as usual)!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
((BorderCell)Cells[i]).Method1();
```

The brackets provide type boundaries if you use them with casting.  Your first attempt didn't wrap the Cell[i].

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
(BorderCell)Cells[i].method1();
```

the cast is applied to the expression `Cells[i].method1();`, which obviously won't work since `Cells[i]` still returns a `Cell`.

If you want to spare an additional variable, then write:

```
((BorderCell)Cells[i]).method1();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you put cells of 2 types (BorderCell and BoardCell) in the array. I would recommend check the type first before casting.

```
if (Cells[i] is BorderCell)
{
// cast to BorderCell
}
else
{
// cast to BoardCell
}
```

Comment: That depends. If the code knows where there should be BorderCells, so is confident that if it's the wrong type, that indicates a bug, then a cast is the right way to do it.

Comment: True, business logic insists, that if a cell is in a specific loaction, then it should have the right type. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140281/what-data-structure-to-use-in-my-example